# How to send message to two services and get response at another one

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I use Spring Integration to send one `Message<Account>` to two different services in parallel, enrich with information them in `AccountService#handleResponse`, wait for both responses (`Message<Account>`) and collect the response in the other. I tried it two different ways.

1.

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow accountFlow() {
return f -> f.handle(accountService, "handle")
        .publishSubscribeChannel(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), configurer -> configurer
                .subscribe(subFlow -> subFlow
                        .handle(accountPersonService, "processAccount")
                        .channel("accountProcessingChannel")
                )
                .subscribe(subFlow -> subFlow
                        .handle(accountPhoneService, "processAccount")
                        .channel("accountProcessingChannel")
                )
        )
        .channel("accountProcessingChannel")
        .handle(accountService, "handleResponse")
        .handle...;
}
```

Thus, I receive a message in `AccountService#handleResponse` as soon as I receive a response from any of them, and then again after a response from the other, and I need one response to come to AccountService#handleResponse, which **will be merged into one**.

2.
I add a new field `boolean isForAccountPerson` to the account and in `AccountService#handle` I set this flag to `true`. Then I copy this message with the `false` flag and in `AccountService#handle` I return `Message<List<Account>>` with two identical accounts, but with different flags in order to follow a different flow

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow accountFlow1() {
return f -> f.handle(accountService, "handle")
        .split()
        .<Account, Boolean>route(Account::isForAccountPerson, mapping -> mapping
                .subFlowMapping(true, sf -> sf.handle(accountPersonService, "processAccount"))
                .subFlowMapping(false, sf -> sf.handle(accountPhoneService, "processAccount"))
        )
        .resequence()
        .aggregate()
        .handle(accountService, "handleResponse")
        .handle...;
}
```

But this way I **don't get any response** in `AccountService#handleResponse.`